Pyspark UDF Mailparser Parsing RFC-822 emails in Synapse - Stuck
I keep running into a problem and it seems like I run into the same problem however i try to work it.
I have a synapse workspace.  I have a storage account that I am pulling raw RFC-822 emails into so that I can get the beginning and end of each email on ADLS Gen2
decided to try writing a UDF, using the python library mail-parser (imported as mailparser) which does a nice job of returning items back into my dataframe.
i am relatively new to spark and wondering the best way to get the body content from the email.  If there is a spark library or something for this I am all ears.
here are my imports:
import mailparser
import sparknlp

from notebookutils import mssparkutils
from sparknlp.base import *
from sparknlp.annotator import *
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, DoubleType, StructField, StructType

spark = sparknlp.start()

print("Spark NLP version", sparknlp.version())
print("Apache Spark version:", spark.version)

spark

reading files from my ADLS Gen2 storage:
my_df = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(f"{DATA_FOLDER_URI}/*").toDF(['path', 'text'])

here is my code for the UDF and a link to the pypi docs:
pypi docs: https://pypi.org/project/mail-parser/
def parsemail(text):
    eml = mailparser.parse_from_string(text)
    fromstr = str(eml.from_)
    date = str(eml.date)
    subject = str(eml.subject)
    mesgid = eml.message_id
    tostr = str(eml.to)
    bodystr = str(eml.text_plain)
    l = []
    l.append(fromstr)
    l.append(date)
    l.append(subject)
    l.append(mesgid)
    l.append(tostr)
    l.append(bodystr)
    return l

then I use lambda function like this:
email_udf = udf(lambda x: parsemail(x), StringType())

checking to make sure things look ok

my_df = my_df.withColumn("emailobj", email_udf('text'))
display(my_df.head(5))

then, before inserting into a table I want to make sure things look relatively clean
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
my_df = my_df.withColumn("FROM", split(my_df["emailobj"], "]").getItem(0)) \
                     .withColumn("DATE", split(my_df["emailobj"], ",").getItem(2)) \
                     .withColumn("SUBJECT", split(my_df["emailobj"], ",").getItem(3)) \
                     .withColumn("TO", split(my_df["emailobj"], "]").getItem(4)) \
                     .withColumn("BODY", split(my_df["emailobj"], "]").getItem(6))


display(my_df.head(1))

I run into issues when I have things like a [ char inside the body, so I was thinking that maybe i should ditch the udf idea all together and use something like a spark regex function because i cannot control what the human writes in the body section and it could be any character.   Or maybe do a regex between to grab the section before the Content-type: text/plain that looks like this:
sample body of an email
--_000_IA0PR19MB7704C52154A5974993EE547FC7582IA0PR19MB7704namp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

  *   10,"the cat in the hat is purple.
  *   Specific to said cat in the hat is that it is also fat and here is a picture [img: cat.png@34IJDIJE.RE4345]
  *   If the cat with the hat doesnt reduce its intake the cat food widget is going to overheat and cost the company $10M in insurance over the next 8 years


--_000_IA0PR19MB7704C52154A5974993EE547FC7582IA0PR19MB7704namp_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

What would you all do?  Open to methods/ideas to creatively deal with this
